# MYSQL JOIN Query Notifications

Tags: php, mysql

I have four tables commenttable, posttable, usertable and notifications table. I want to build a notifications system. The notifications table has the following

```
column id,
notifier,
notifying,
date,
type,
typeid
```

Type could be either 1 or 2. If it's 1, it's a comment and if it's 2, it's a post.

I want to build a MySQL query which gets all the notifications for a user and joins them with the commenttable, posttable depending on the type. For instance if type is 1 and type id is 300 then it would pull the comment column from the commmentable and if its 2 then it would pull the post column from the post table.

The columns in post are as follows:

```
postid, post and commenttable commenter, comment, commentid
```

I had built a query as follows but it doesn't work like i want it to

```
SELECT 
    notificationstable.who,
    notificationstable.type,
    notificationstable.timestamp,
    notificationstable.date,
    commenttable.comment,
    commenttable.commentid,
    usertable.username,
    usertable.avatar,
    usertable.userid,
    usertable.verified,
    posttable.photo,
    posttable.title,
    posttable.postid
from
    notificationstable
        inner join
    usertable
        inner join
    posttable
        inner join
    commenttable ON notificationstable.who = usertable.userid 
 and posttable.postid = notificationstable.type 
 and commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.type
where
    notificationstable.whom = '$userid'
order by notificationstable.date desc
```

`$userid` is a php variable

Comment: "it doesn't work like i want it to" is a really bad problem description if you want people to help you.

Comment: What is it doing that is not what you expected? What are you expecting?

Comment: What results is it giving you?  What results do you expect.  It would be helpful if you were to put the tables and some data into SQL Fiddle for us to work with.

Comment: Not having a question mark in a question might hint that it's not a question.

Comment: `userrable` looks like a typo to me for a start! And I don't like those inner joins without an `ON`clause

Comment: there is an ON clause

Comment: "I have three tables commenttable, posttable, usertable and notifications table." hehe

Comment: So what is undesirable about what you have? For example, maybe you can shed some light for us on what it does not do that you want it to?, what it does do that you do not want it to?, if you get any output?, if so what does it show?, if not do you get an error?, if so what is it?, if not is it running properly?, ...?, ...?, etc. I'd be willing to help and I'm sure others would too but we don't have anything to go on. So far we know there's a problem with your code running on your computer...doesn't get much broader than that.

Comment: @Kwaasi, if you have `ON` clauses in the actual SQL you are running, please edit that into your question.

Comment: @halfer, it is there?

Comment: How does the notifications table interact with the posttable and commenttable? Is there a column that tracks the commentid/postid?

Comment: @budwiser, ah yes - I've not seen that approach before! The syntax is usually `INNER JOIN totable ON (fromtable.x = totable.y)`, repeated as required. See kickstart's answer as an example. The `AND` clause is only necessary, imo, for composite joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you mean to do outer joins, given it seems a notification can't apply to both posttable and the commenttable

Something like this

```
SELECT 
    notificationstable.who,
    notificationstable.type,
    notificationstable.timestamp,
    notificationstable.date,
    commenttable.comment,
    commenttable.commentid,
    usertable.username,
    usertable.avatar,
    usertable.userid,
    usertable.verified,
    posttable.photo,
    posttable.title,
    posttable.postid
FROM notificationstable
INNER JOIN usertable
ON notificationstable.who = usertable.userid
LEFT OUTER JOIN posttable
ON posttable.postid = notificationstable.type
LEFT OUTER JOIN commenttable 
ON commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.type
WHERE notificationstable.whom = '$userid'
ORDER BY notificationstable.date DESC
```

Comment: From the OP's post, I don't know what it should be, but I think `posttable.postid = notificationstable.type` is a problem. He says that type is either 1 or 2, where if it is a 1 you should execute a commenttable query or 2 you should execute a posttable query. I think `OUTER JOIN commenttable ON commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.whatever_the_heck_the_column_name_corresponding_to_the_comment_or_post_id_is` is the idea.

Comment: I'm not a MYSQL ninja, but could you do something like this: `...CASE WHEN notificationstable.type = 1 THEN INNER JOIN commenttable ON commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.still_need_this_column ELSE INNER JOIN posttable ON posttable.postid = notificationstable.still_need_this_column` and possibly do something similar with the select?

Comment: I think you could be right, but difficult to make out from the original post. I have taken his query (which didn't try to use that) and modified it to use outer joins. With inner joins if the notifications type defines whether it is a post table or comment table then both can't match at the same time to both a post and a comment. You could do LEFT JOINs and then use a CASE (or just an IF) to define which tables columns to return as a particular column.

Comment: I thought about using case so that case type is 1 then the post columns in the query putput would be null and vice versa if the type is 2. That is ideally how I would want the output @kickstart

Comment: Using a LEFT JOIN the non matched columns will be NULL anyway

Comment: Make sure you change `commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.type` to `commenttable.commentid = notificationstable.typeid` and the same for posttable